# hive on hbase can't get data

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

Table info as follows

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `my_table`(
  `rowkey` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `col_1` string COMMENT 'from deserializer',
  `col_2` int COMMENT 'from deserializer')
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseSerDe' 
STORED BY 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'hbase.columns.mapping'=':key,cf1:col_1,cf1:col_2,
  'serialization.format'='1')
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE'='false', 
  'hbase.table.name'='test:my_hbase_table', 
  'numFiles'='0', 
  'numRows'='-1', 
  'rawDataSize'='-1', 
  'totalSize'='0', 
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1487578220')
```

Sql as follows

```
hive> select col_1 from my_table where col_1 = '123';
OK
Time taken: 0.322 seconds
hive> select * from my_table where col_1 = '123';
OK
123 123 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
Time taken: 0.198 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive> select col_1,* from my_table where col_1 = '123';
OK
123 123 123 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

I don't know why i can get data mast add **select *** only , thank you for your answer~

Comment: Is the issue resolved ? If not can you tell the version of Hadoop, Hive and HBase which you are using ?